# recyclerview in view pager won't load

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-glide

I am developing an android app with multiple tabs using viewpager. However, one of the tabs which contain recyclerview just keep on loading non stop as shown in the attached screenshot. The recyclerview contains a list of images. I am able to load imageview and textview in other tabs successfully, only this tab which contain recyclerview has issue.

Adapter:

```
 public class MasterListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MasterListAdapter.Holder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Integer> mImageIds;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    @BindView(R.id.images_list_view) ImageView imageView;

    public MasterListAdapter(Context context, List<Integer> imageIds) {
        mContext = context;
        mImageIds = imageIds;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new Holder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
        Glide.with(mContext).load(mImageIds.get(position)).apply(RequestOptions.fitCenterTransform()).into(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mImageIds.size();
    }

    public class Holder extends ViewHolder {

        public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

        }
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
    public class ListFragment extends BaseFragment {
    @BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    int getLayoutId() {
        return R.layout.fragment_list;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MasterListAdapter(getContext(),ImageAssets.getImages()));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    }
}
```

ImageAssets:

```
public class ImageAssets {

private static final List<Integer> images = new ArrayList<Integer>() {{
    add(R.drawable.user);
    //add(R.drawable.img2);
    //add(R.drawable.img3);
    //add(R.drawable.img4);
    //add(R.drawable.img5);
    //add(R.drawable.img6);
    //add(R.drawable.img7);
    //add(R.drawable.img8);
    //add(R.drawable.img9);
    //add(R.drawable.img10);
    //add(R.drawable.img11);
    //add(R.drawable.img12);
    //add(R.drawable.img13);
}};

public static List<Integer> getImages() {
    return images;
}
}
```

Viewpager:

```
    static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return Page.values()[position].getFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return Page.values()[position].getTitle();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Page.values().length;
    }
}

enum Page {
    First("View") {
        @Override
        Fragment getFragment() {return new ListFragment();}
    };

    private String title;

    Page(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    abstract Fragment getFragment();
}
```

list_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/images_list_view"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:src="@drawable/user">

</ImageView>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Update:**

Hi all, thank you for all your value responses to my post. I have figured out the cause of the infinite loading issue. It was because I imported ListFragment in MainActivity accidentally which has the exact same name as my fragment class. Removing the import solved the issue.

Comment: what is `ImageAssets` ? ( please post that code )

Comment: posted the code. ImageAssets will return a list of images in drawable.

Comment: updated the answer please check

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
    @BindView(R.id.images_list_view) ImageView imageView;
```

try this :-

```
public class Holder extends ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
       imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.images_list_view);
}
```

and in `onBind`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {     
  Glide.with(mContext)
       .load(mImageIds.get(position))
       .apply(RequestOptions.fitCenterTransform())
       .into(holder.imageView);
}
```

As you are calling a static reference your `ImageAssets` constructor is never getting called.. so get the correct list of images try this in your fragment :-

```
private void init() {
    ImageAssets imageAssets = new ImageAssets(); // add this line to get the images 
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MasterListAdapter(getContext(),ImageAssets.getImages()));
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
}
```

Make constructor in `ImageAssets` class and initialize `images` there !!

Comment: I've tried this before. It's still not working. The loading screen appears and loading forever.

Comment: just tried to add constructor and initialize. still not working

Comment: can you post your `item xml layout` of the recyclerView or your `list_view.xml` @chunwai

Answer (score 0):

Found your problem. You forgot to bind your view inside Holder class.

```
public class MasterListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MasterListAdapter.Holder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Integer> mImageIds;
private LayoutInflater inflater;



public MasterListAdapter(Context context, List<Integer> imageIds) {
    mContext = context;
    mImageIds = imageIds;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new Holder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {
    Glide.with(mContext).load(mImageIds.get(position)).apply(RequestOptions.fitCenterTransform()).into(holder.imageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mImageIds.size();
}

public class Holder extends ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.images_list_view) ImageView imageView;
    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}
```

}

**Fragment**

```
public class ListFragment extends BaseFragment {
@BindView(R.id.recyclerView)
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
int getLayoutId() {
    return R.layout.fragment_list;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MasterListAdapter(getContext(),ImageAssets.getImages()));
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
}
```

}

Comment: @chunwai you also forgot to bind your RecyclerView inside ListFragment class. Please check updated answer how to bind view inside Fragment.

In addition, BaseFragment was deprecated in API level 27.1.0, extends Fragment or BaseSupportFragment  instead.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/BaseFragment.html